# $_GET variable into fpdf

Tags: php, fpdf

Hoe can i get the below $_GET variables into fpdf

```
//User Details
$Name = $_GET['name'];
$Surname = $_GET['surname'];
$City = $_GET['city'];
$CountryCode = $_GET['countrycode'];
$Phone = $_GET['phone'];
$Email = $_GET['email'];

<?php
include('includes/fpdf.php');
$Name = $_GET['name'];
$Surname = $_GET['surname'];
$City = $_GET['city'];
$CountryCode = $_GET['countrycode'];
$Phone = $_GET['phone'];
$Email = $_GET['email'];
class PDF extends FPDF
{
// Page header
function Header()
{
```

I need to create a pdf after a form submission and let the user print the file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with fpdf at all but in your class methods you would do something like

```
$pdf = new PDF();
$pdf->someMethod($Name);
```

Which would pass you $Name variable into that method

Answer (score 0):

```
include('includes/fpdf.php');

public $Name = "";

class PDF extends FPDF
{

    function XYZ()
    {
        $this->Name = $_GET["name"];
     }
}

 This is the way of receiving the data in a class. But its more better if
 you read the fpdf documentation, in which you can get more information 
 about generating the pdf.
```

Answer (score -1):

The FPDF API seems to be an entire library of functions and features.

Writing how to use all the functions here would be a waste of time, so please find documentation of FPDF in other locations.

Here is the first link I found that appears to be fruitful:

- [Generating PDF files with PHP and FPDF](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/generating-pdf-files-with-php-and-fpdf/)